# How to convert io.swagger.annotation.SecurityDefinition to io.swagger.v3.oas.annotations.security.SecurityScheme

Tags: java, openapi, swagger-3.0

I am migrating from old swagger to new `Swagger 3.0`
I have this in config

```java
@SwaggerDefinition(securityDefinition = @SecurityDefinition(apiKeyAuthDefinitions = {
    @ApiKeyAuthDefinition(description = "Authentication token", key = "token", in = ApiKeyAuthDefinition.ApiKeyLocation.HEADER, name = "X-Access-Token"),
    @ApiKeyAuthDefinition(description = "JWT (token3)", key = "jwt", in = ApiKeyAuthDefinition.ApiKeyLocation.HEADER, name = "Authorization") })
)
public interface ApiConfig {
}
```

and below is my old impl class

```java
@Api(value = "Setup API: Agreement", authorizations = {@Authorization(value = "jwt"), @Authorization(value = "token")})
//@SecurityRequirement(name = "token")
@RequestScoped
@Interceptors(EndpointMonitoringInterceptor.class)
public class ApiServiceImpl extends CommonRestBaseService implements AgreementApi {
}
```

Thanks in advance

I know `@Api` will be converted to `@Tag` for eg.

```java
@Tag(name = "Setup API: Agreement")
@SecurityRequirement(name = "token")
@SecurityRequirement(name = "jwt")` <-- I may be wrong to have separate secuirty requirement here
```